# I have moved Odoo Server and Database to another machine. Why can't I load my CSS?

Tags: python, css, ubuntu-16.04, odoo, odoo-10

I deployed odoo 10 CE on my local Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS with nginx reverse proxy. Now i installed Ubuntu 16.04, Odoo 10 CE with nginx as reverse proxy on another server. I restored the database from old server to new server.

If i access my new server like http://x.x.x.x:8069 , it works fine.

But access like http://x.x.x.x , the login page shows with out css styling. After login can't see any menus, company logo only.

[image]

If i try with `Private browsing` it works fine.

How can i resolve this.

**EDIT**

I ran the odoo server in two ways, first ran directly from the terminal like :

` sudo su - odoo -s /bin/bash

/odoo/odoo-server/./odoo-bin`

then i access like `<ip_address>:8069`, it works fine.

But when i try to run as demon ( sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server start) , i face the same problem.

My system user is: odooadmin

odoo user is : odoo

And if i access via debug mode with assets it woks fine.

```
 <ip_address>:8069/web?debug=assets
```

Any solution?

Comment: What do you mean Private browsing?

Comment: `Incognito Window`..

Comment: You said that if using private browsing, it works then there is something with the cache. When you clear the browser cache, you also need to restart the browser. Unless if you stated that private browsing also has problem, then there will be other answers for you.

Comment: I tried each and every solution listed on this page, but none of them listed works, in my case CSS, specifically leaflet.css is not getting loaded when I am trying to restore the database from the restore database option, are there different sets of steps when restoring the database.

Answer (score 4):

If you moved to another machine there might be issue with loading some assets cached at the level of odoo server, such as transpiled js code for instance.

In order to solve this issue, you should (after restoring the database) connect to your database and run the following command :

`DELETE FROM ir_attachment WHERE url LIKE '/web/content/%';`.

More information here : https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/13808

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you can get an `Internal Server Error 500`. In other cases you can get what you got. There are a few things you can try:

1. **Remove Browser Cache**. You can press `Shift + Ctrl + Supr`. Or reload without cache with `Ctrl + F5`
2. **Remove Cookies**. If you are using chrome or chromium you can delete the cookies stored for the domain you are using as you can see in the images:

[image: cookies removal]

3. **`web.base.url` Parameter**. Activate deleloper mode. Go to **Settings > Parameters > System Parameters** and check that the parameter `web.base.url` is correctly set. This parameter is updated each time you log in with the Administrator user, the value of the url bar is assigned to the parameter. But if you can get it to work with the private mode I assume this is well assigned.

Comment: Hi ChesuCr, it tried you solution but didn't work for me. I updated my question, could you take a look?

Comment: Are you using the same user in the service? Also check if you have permissions to write into the `data_dir = /opt/odoo/.local/share/odoo`, you should have this path in the configuration file. All of this is with NginX running? First, try if Odoo is working well without NginX.

Answer (score 2):

Did you compile your CSS?

If it looks funnyou may need lessc CSS compiling (from https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/setup/install.html )

We symlink node because some versions of debian/ubuntu don't agree on the bin name

## Install Node

```
sudo apt install -y nodejs npm
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

## Compiling CSS

If you install less, odoo will automatically compile the CSS

```
sudo npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css
```

## Consider blowing away the file cache:

If the compilation had failed, sometimes you need to blow away the postgres cache, 
(thanks to [sebalix](https://github.com/OCA/ansible-odoo/issues/85) for this tip):

You can run this SQL query in postgres to let Odoo rebuild its CSS+JS assets + reload icons via [dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/):

```
DELETE FROM ir_attachment WHERE datas_fname SIMILAR TO '%.(js|css)';
DELETE FROM ir_attachment WHERE name='web_icon_data';
```

Then restart the server (assuming it was installed via [ansible](https://github.com/OCA/ansible-odoo))

```
sudo service odoo restart
```

There's also files in `~/.local/share/Odoo/filestore` you may want to temporarily move/rename

## Check postgres version

Some versions of postgres are not supported, check `psql --version` and that you can download a backup of your database

## Check odoo version

I've seen installs where `odoo-bin --version` returns 10 but the logs show `odoo11` before every log line

Comment: _"Did you compile your CSS?"_ You don't have to manually compile LESS files. Odoo does that for us.

Comment: @VinhVO I think you're right, but I one time accidentally deleted the CSS files from the `~/.local/share/Odoo/filestore`... how can I trigger the compilation again?

Comment: I didn't test this, but every time I restart the server (odoo service) and reload the page, everything should be OK. I'm on Odoo 11.

Answer (score 1):

I think your browser has some files on cache. Can you try after delete cache files on your browser ?